# notifyDatasetchanged not working for ArrayAdapter

Tags: arraylist, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to implement 2 AutoCompleteTextView. First one holds the value, on click of one of them will populate the data in second AutoCompleteTextView, all works and data gets loaded correctly however when I try to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the second adapter which populates the second field that does not get changed.

I also wrote that piece of code inside a Handler too, however that does not seems to work either.

```
branchAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,branchNames);
et7.setAdapter(branchAdapter);//et7 is the AutoCompleteTextView //branchname is the ArrayList
```

in some method I clean up the ArrayList and add the new data into it and then call notifyDataSetChanged like below

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         branchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
  });
```

Which is not updating the list. What should be the correct way here to update data?

Comment: Are you modifying the ArrayList via the adapter or via your own external list (eg `branchNames`)? Can you show that portion of the code?

Answer (score 1):

@Saty, I guess i am a little late to the party. I am answering, keeping in mind that, it may help somebody in future.
Cleanup the adapter as well using branchAdapter.clear() method. Then add new items to the adapter using branchAdapter.addAll(String... items) method. Now, call branchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting listview instead.

```
             ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
             ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(/*with all parameters*/);
             lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```